# How do you detect the issue causes Passenger application instances keeps consuming more and more memory?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, passenger

Here it comes:
I have a Rails application running on a RedHat server. I use Passenger Standalone v3.0.19 to serve it. The database is MySQL.
Recently I found that some of the Passenger Application instances keeps consuming more and more memory every minute, and these instances are not actually useful. (When I request a page, Passenger will spawn a new instance instead of using this ones) I tried to kill such Instances manually (not the right way to deal with problems, I know), but after a couple of hours it happens again.

This is what I got by passenger-memory-stats:

```
------- Apache processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


---------- Nginx processes ----------
PID    PPID   VMSize   Private  Name
-------------------------------------
48881  1      27.6 MB  0.1 MB   nginx: master process    /home/myuser/.passenger/standalone/3.0.19-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.7-1002/nginx-1.2.6/sbin/nginx -c /tmp/passenger-standalone.48333/config -p /tmp/passenger-standalone.48333/
48882  48881  28.5 MB  0.7 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.78 MB

------- Passenger processes -------
PID    VMSize      Private    Name
-----------------------------------
48841  207.3 MB    0.1 MB     PassengerWatchdog
48844  1822.7 MB   1.7 MB     PassengerHelperAgent
48846  247.2 MB    14.3 MB    Passenger spawn server
48850  143.0 MB    0.5 MB     PassengerLoggingAgent
63729  10006.3 MB  9097.2 MB  Rack: /home/myuser/webapp/current
76631  999.0 MB    92.3 MB    Rack: /home/myuser/webapp/current
```

This is the passenger-status output:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 1
active   = 0
inactive = 1
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/myuser/webapp/current:
  App root: /home/myuser/webapp/current
  * PID: 76631   Sessions: 0    Processed: 15      Uptime: 51m 7s
```

Apparently the process 63729 is not managed by Passenger anymore.

I also used strace, by running:

```
strace -f -p 63729
```

I got:

```
[pid 63729] read(14, "\1\0\0\1\1\36\0\0\2\3def\0\0\0\10COUNT(*)\0\f?\0\25\0\0"..., 16384) = 63
[pid 63729] brk(0x234f2c000)            = 0x234f2c000
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 63729] write(14, "\221\0\0\0\3SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_"..., 149) = 149
[pid 63729] ppoll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=14, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 63729] read(14, "\1\0\0\1\1\36\0\0\2\3def\0\0\0\10COUNT(*)\0\f?\0\25\0\0"..., 16384) = 63
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 63729] write(14, "\221\0\0\0\3SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_"..., 149) = 149
[pid 63729] ppoll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 1, NULL, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=14, revents=POLLIN}])
[pid 63729] read(14, "\1\0\0\1\1\36\0\0\2\3def\0\0\0\10COUNT(*)\0\f?\0\25\0\0"..., 16384) = 63
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
[pid 63729] poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 63729] write(14, "\221\0\0\0\3SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_"..., 149) = 149
```

And the same pattern keeps on and on. I checked fd 14 with code

```
ls -l /proc/63729/fd
```

And This is what I got:

```
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 1 -> /home/myuser/webapp/shared/log/passenger.log
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 10 -> socket:[430845495]
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 11 -> socket:[430860531]
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 12 -> socket:[430845847]
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 13 -> socket:[430845850]
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 14 -> socket:[430845864]
l-wx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 2 -> /home/myuser/webapp/shared/log/passenger.log
l-wx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 3 ->     /home/myuser/webapp/shared/log/production.log
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 4 -> pipe:[430845856]
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 5 -> pipe:[430845845]
l-wx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 6 -> pipe:[430845845]
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 7 -> pipe:[430845846]
l-wx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 8 -> pipe:[430845856]
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 May  9 05:38 9 -> socket:[430845494]
```

This is where I'm stucking now. I don't know how to get the request from the socket id, or get the SQL command from strace, but I guess the problem might be the abuse of SQL or ActiveRecord. Could anybody help me on this? I don't know if there is any info missing but I'll provide it on demand. Any thing will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anything crazy in your slow_query.log?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, cih. However the slow query log is turned of and I have no privilege to turn it on. I've filed a request to IT and they will turn it on for me. I'll update this post once I got the log content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by checking the mysql log. slow_query_log doesn't have anything wrong. But the general_log shows that a series of querying keeps looking for older records. It was due to a silly code I wrote for active record. I guess I'll close this question now.

Comment: Very interesting! I've been really stuck on this same problem! I will double check my code for errors now!